# Lambda function as composable function parameter

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I was trying to search online but couldn't find a clear answer.

Why some libraries declare their composable function variable as lambda for example

```
data class ScreenState(count:Int)

@Composable
fun Test(){
   val screenState = viewModel.screenState.collectAsState()
   //Version 1
   Counter(screenState.count)

   //Version 2
   Counter({
     screenState.count
   })

}


//Version 1

@Composable
fun Counter(count: Int){
   Text(count))
}


//Version 2

@Composable
fun Counter(count: ()->Unit){
   Text(count())
}
```

Why some mention that version 2 make use of smart recompositions while version 1 not.

Is there a technical explanation to it?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the contents of the lambda are only executed when needed. Now, there wouldn't be an advantage if the parameter was a simple value:

```
Counter(3)     // Version 1
Counter({ 3 }) // Version 2
```

Both work fine, even when the containing composable is recomposed a lot.
However, imagine the parameter must be calculated:

```
Counter(findMillionthPrime())     // Version 1
Counter({ findMillionthPrime() }) // Version 2
```

In the first version `findMillionthPrime` will be executed on every recomposition just to find out that it always results in the same value and then the recomposition of the `Counter` is skipped. When this is, for example, part of an animation the recomposition could occur every single frame. Doing the same costly calculation over and over again in such a time-critical scenario would result in a laggy, stuttering UI.

The second version, however, is detected to not have changed during recomposition right away, since the parameter hasn't changed: It's still the same lambda. Remember: The lambda is just a description of what *should* be done at some later point. It isn't actually executed at the time where it is declared. Only when `Counter` is executed, `findMillionthPrime()` will be executed.

This example is, of course, somewhat contrived. On the other hand, Compose is designed in such a way that composables should only do light work and finish as fast as possible. You could therefore experience problems much earlier when you repeat even simple calculations unnecessarily. Then it comes in handy when the calculation can be deferred to a later time.